# Include COUNT (including 0) of grouped records

Tags: mysql, sql, join, grouping

I have a table like below

```
answers:
| room | answer |
|------|--------|
| 001  | 3      |
| 002  | 6      |
| 002  | 5      |
| 002  | 6      |
```

I want to count the answers for each room. That's pretty easy, but I also want the zero values for each room and each possible answer (distinct of all answers) like shown below

```
| room | answer | answerCount |
|------|--------|-------------|
| 001  | 3      | 1           |
| 001  | 5      | 0           |
| 001  | 6      | 0           |
| 002  | 3      | 0           |
| 002  | 5      | 1           |
| 002  | 6      | 2           |
```

I already had a hard time solving this problem, hope you guys can help me? :)

Comment: Not really that “difficult”: the complicated bit is determining the range of numbers to be able to detect “missing” answers. This problem is much simpler if also having the set of possible answers. Make sure titles are representative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using a self join where one side of join statement containing a distinctly selected set for **answer**s

```
SELECT a1.room,  a2.answer, SUM( a1.answer=a2.answer ) AS answerCount 
  FROM answers a1
  JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT answer FROM answers ) a2
 GROUP BY a1.room, a2.answer
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6b6ba372998b1f607cde68dd804707bd)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much! This query solves my problem as well and I understand this query, it suddenly seems much easier. :)

Comment: you're welcome, good luck @Jordy , btw, case of stickybit works also ( I suggest you to upvote it , too ).

Answer (score 1):

You can cross join derived tables selecting the distinct rooms or answer respectively, then left join to it, aggregate and get the count.

```
SELECT x1.room,
       x2.answer,
       count(t3.room) answercount
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    t1.room
                    FROM elbat t1) x1
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                               t2.answer
                               FROM elbat t2) x2
            LEFT JOIN elbat t3
                      ON t3.room = x1.room
                         AND t3.answer = x2.answer
       GROUP BY x1.room,
                x2.answer
       ORDER BY x1.room,
                x2.answer;
```

Ideally though, you should have a table with all rooms and another one with all answers and cross join them instead of the derived tables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! When running this query I get the following error: `Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table: 't1'`

Comment: Found the problem! I hade an issue with temporary tables. Thanks for your solution!